# microsoft graph api - Cannot create mail subscription error: ServiceUnavailable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When we were trying to create a email subscription with an email account, we got the ServiceUnavailable error.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

Body: {
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "***********************",
   "resource": "me/messages",
   "expirationDateTime":"2019-09-11T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "****"
}
```

Response is

```
{
    "error":{
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: ServiceUnavailable; Reason: Target resource '0003bffd-d62b-a260-0000-000000000000' hosted on database '8cea8e2c-3c39-469c-a9e7-3f0bed47d869' is currently on backend 'Unknown']",
        "innerError":{
        "request-id": "972e7800-541e-41f9-8792-069ecd564345",
        "date": "2019-09-09T23:30:13"
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the reason for this kind of error?

Comment: any update on this? i'm currently experiencing a similar issue

Comment: I am receiving the same error when subscribing to calendar events. No idea what is the cause.